# Al ocultar un Group contenido en un menú (action group) obtengo un error

Tags: genexus

Necesito ocultar un Group contenido en un menú (action group) y no encuentro la forma

Cuando menciono el objeto para intentar asignarle una clase css que lo oculte me da error:
Control/object 'nombreDelObjeto' not found/defined. Is it on the form?

Estoy trabajando con Gx17u9 generando .net

Comment: Hola por favor añade el código con el que estas trabajando, para que la comunidad pueda ayudar.